# How to find the difference between two lists that contain lists in Python?

Tags: python, list

If we have

```
X1=[[a,b,c],[a,e,t],[a,b,c]]
```

and

```
X2=[[a,b,c]]
```

I want to find the difference between X1 and X2 which is:

```
X3=X1-X2=[[a,b,c],[a,e,t]].
```

So my output should contain two lists not one as I only want to remove one [a,b,c] not both.

I am doing it in this way but I get error:

```
s = set(X2)
X3 = [x for x in X1 if x not in s]
```

The error I get is this:

```
unhashable type: 'list'
```

I get this error when the program get to this point:

```
s = set(X2)
```

Comment: What would be the value of `X3`?

Comment: X3 should be [[a,b,c],[a,e,t]] as I want only one [a,b,c] be removed from the X1 not both.

Answer (score 4):

So, `X3 = [a,e,t]`, right?

There is no need to convert it to set. You can do this:

`result = [x for x in X1 if x not in X2]`.

Comment: This will fail if the order of the items in the sublists are not the same

Comment: X3 should be [[a,b,c],[a,e,t]]  as I want only one [a,b,c] be removed from the X1 not both.

Comment: Oh okay, then you should update your question with this info.

Answer (score 1):

lists are *unhashable* so they cannot be members of a `set`. You can convert the inner lists into a `frozenset`, so two sublists with the same items but different ordering are still considered same and then use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to find the *difference* between both lists:

```
from collections import Counter

X3 = Counter([frozenset(i) for i in X1]) - Counter([frozenset(i) for i in X2])
print(X3)
# Counter({frozenset({'c', 'a', 'b'}): 1, frozenset({'e', 'a', 't'}): 1})

print(X3.keys())
# [frozenset({'e', 't', 'a'}), frozenset({'c', 'b', 'a'})]
```

A [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is a subclass of a `dict`, so you can return the difference as a list by using `.keys()`:

```
print(X3.keys()) # or print(list(X3.keys())) in Python 3.x
# [frozenset({'e', 't', 'a'}), frozenset({'c', 'b', 'a'})]
```

If you need to keep your inner `list`s, you can replace the `frozenset` with lists by doing:

```
X3 = [list(i) for i in X3.keys()]

print(X3)
# [['a', 't', 'e'], ['c', 'a', 'b']]
```

Comment: X3 should be [[a,b,c],[a,e,t]]  as I want only one [a,b,c] be removed from the X1 not both.

Comment: This does not even give me  a list

Comment: Did you try `.keys()`?

Comment: Yes. It gives me a list that contains one frozen set

Comment: I guess you're using my old answer. I've updated that.

Comment: Man. This this does not work. How do you get those outputs? I still get a list with one element

Comment: Well, you may want to check the data you are using. This is nothing close to magic

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, lists are unhashable (because they're mutable). Convert your list of lists into a list of tuples, which are hashable:

```
>>> hash((1, 2, 3))
2528502973977326415
>>> hash([1, 2, 3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

In your case, you could do:

```
s = set(map(tuple, X2))
```

Comment: Or `set = {tuple(sublist) for sublist in X2}` if you prefer comprehensions.

Comment: @Daerdemandt since the map doesn't involve a lambda it is probably faster. Also, it's a lot cleaner/more readable.

Comment: Yes, maps are usually faster. Many people still prefer comprehensions though. As for 'a lot cleaner/more readable', that's subjective.